# Query Cassandra table through Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to get values from Cassandra 2.0.17 table through spark-1.6.0 and scala-2.11.7 with the following steps

1. Started cassandra -- service cassandra start
2. Started spark--  sbin/start-all.sh
3. stated spark scala -- bin/spark-shell --jars spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.5.0-M1.jar

executed these commands in scala

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

sc.stop

val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","127.0.0.1")

val sc=new SparkContext("local[2]","test",conf)

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

everything works fine till here, but when i execute -

```
val rdd=sc.cassandraTable("tutorialspoint","emp")
```

It gives me the below error

```
error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in CassandraTableScanRDD.class refers to term driver
in package com.datastax which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling CassandraTableScanRDD.class.
error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in CassandraTableScanRDD.class refers to term core
in value com.datastax.driver which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling CassandraTableScanRDD.class.
error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in CassandraTableScanRDD.class refers to term core
in value com.datastax.driver which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling CassandraTableScanRDD.class.
```

Have added jars from cassandra lib to spark and refrenced it.
 my using java version 1.8.0_72

M i missing some thing?

Comment: this link may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641995/nosuchmethoderror-from-spark-cassandra-connector-with-assembled-jar/34645885#34645885. Do remember to use the compatible version of Cassandra jar files with the Spark version.

Comment: ok there are issue in Cassandra version and then the jar versions. have to un-install everything..

Comment: now i have used cassandra 2.2.4 spark 1.6.0 scala-2.11.7 and jar spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11-1.5.0-RC1 , and all the given jar u had mentioned. it solved that error but now when i println(rdd.first) it gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.zero()Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;

Comment: solved it buy downgrading to spark1.4 thanks

Comment: Great....if the solution provided in my first comment works then please vote for it. It will help others.

Answer (score 1):

The driver you are using is incompatible with your scala and spark version. You are using scala-2.11.7, but this driver is for scala 2.10. Also for spark this driver supports spark 1.5.x.

Comment: now i have used cassandra 2.2.4 spark 1.6.0 scala-2.11.7 and jar spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11-1.5.0-RC1 , and all the given jar u had mentioned. it solved that error but now when i println(rdd.first) it gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.zero()Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;

Comment: Spark distro is built with scala 2.10 and include scala 2.10 in assembly. Thus your spark-shell reported that it run on 2.10. 
So build spark by your self  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211 or use scala_2.10 connector